# Let $f:[0,1] -> R$ continuous function $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)<1$. Show that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ there's $c \in [0,1]$ with $f(c)=\sqrt[n]{c}$.

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with the property that $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)<1$. Show that , for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=\sqrt[n]{c}$.

I considered defining a function $g(x) = [f(x)]^n$ and using the fixed point theorem (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FixedPointTheorem.html) on $g(x)$.

However, even though we have $f(1)<1$ implies $g(1)<1$ and $f(0)>0$ implies $g(0)>0$, we cannot guarantee that $0<g(x)<1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Consider an application of the Intermediate Value Theorem instead.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $n \in \mathbb N$, Define $g(x) := f(x) - x^{1/n}$. This is a continuous function such that $g(0) > 0$ and $g(1) <0$. Therefore, $\exists$ a $c \in (0,1)$ such that $g(c) = 0$.